# Merge some rows into one when the data is continuous

Tags: r, dplyr, bioinformatics

I have a [bed file](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat#format1) which is loaded as a dataframe into R. Genomic coordinates that looks something likes this:

```
chrom   start  end
chrX    400    600
chrX    800    1000
chrX    1000   1200
chrX    1200   1400
chrX    1600   1800
chrX    2000   2200
chrX    2200   2400
```

There's no need to keep all the rows and it would be nicer to compact it to something like this:

```
chrom   start  end
chrX    400    600
chrX    800    1400
chrX    1600   1800
chrX    2000   2400
```

How can I possibly do it?

I've tried to think of something with `dplyr` but no success. `group_by` wouldn't work because I don't know how to modify chunks of continuous rows into one using start coordinate from the first row and end coordinate from the last row also because there are many of these chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package from bioconductor, built specifically for bed files and the like:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

# Example data
gr <- GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle("chr1", 6),
  ranges = IRanges(start = c(400 ,800, 1200, 1400, 1800, 2000),
                   end = c(600, 1000, 1400, 1600, 2000, 2200)))
gr
# GRanges object with 6 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
#       seqnames       ranges strand
#          <Rle>    <IRanges>  <Rle>
#   [1]     chr1 [ 400,  600]      *
#   [2]     chr1 [ 800, 1000]      *
#   [3]     chr1 [1200, 1400]      *
#   [4]     chr1 [1400, 1600]      *
#   [5]     chr1 [1800, 2000]      *
#   [6]     chr1 [2000, 2200]      *
#   -------
#   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

# merge contiouse ranges into one using reduce:
reduce(gr)
# GRanges object with 4 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
#       seqnames       ranges strand
#          <Rle>    <IRanges>  <Rle>
#   [1]     chr1 [ 400,  600]      *
#   [2]     chr1 [ 800, 1000]      *
#   [3]     chr1 [1200, 1600]      *
#   [4]     chr1 [1800, 2200]      *
#   -------
#   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlength

# EDIT: if the bed file is a data.frame we can convert it to ranges object:
gr <- GRanges(seqnames(Rle(df$chrom),
                       ranges = IRanges(start = df$start,
                                        end = df$end)))
```